# Liberty Server: isUserInRole always return false

Tags: security, jax-rs, websphere-liberty

I have a JaxRS 2.0 EAR Application deployed on Liberty Server 20.0.0.9

I read all possible documentation e all questions on stackoverflow but I didn't find any solution.

I have an API protected with annotation RolesAllowed but when invoking I always got 403 Http Code.

This is my configuration:

web.xml

```
<!-- SECURITY ROLES -->
<security-role><role-name>Pippo</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR</role-name></security-role>
<security-role><role-name>cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT</role-name></security-role>

<!-- SECURITY CONSTRAINTS -->
<security-constraint>
    <display-name>Test Back Office Constraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Test Back Office</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/testbo/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>Pippo</role-name>
        <role-name>LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR</role-name>
        <role-name>cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<!-- AUTHENTICATION METHOD: Basic authentication -->
<login-config>
    <auth-method>MP-JWT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

ibmapplication-bnd.xml

```
<security-role name="AllAuthenticated">
     <special-subject type="ALL_AUTHENTICATED_USERS" />
</security-role>
<security-role name="Pippo">
    <group name="cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT" />
</security-role>
<security-role name="LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR">
    <group name="cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT" />
</security-role>
<security-role name="cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT">
    <group name="cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT" />
</security-role>
```

Application class

```
@LoginConfig(authMethod = "MP-JWT")

@ApplicationPath("website")
public class WebsiteApplication extends Application {
```

My Api

```
@ApplicationScoped
@DeclareRoles({"Pippo", "LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR", "cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT"})
public class BackOfficeApiTestResource extends BaseApiResource implements BackOfficeTestApi {

    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT")
    public void test1() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test 1 called");
    }
    
    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR")
    public void test2() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test 1 called");
    }
    
    @Override
    @RolesAllowed("Pippo")
    public void test3() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("test 2 called");
    }
}
```

JWT Token Content

```
{
  "sub": "btelefonicacv",
  "token_type": "Bearer",
  "scope": [
    "api"
  ],
  "jti": "6JBgVnsl7s1eaI3v",
  "iss": "https://localhost:9445/oidc/endpoint/OP",
  "exp": 1617289174,
  "iat": 1617281974,
  "givenName": "MARIO",
  "sn": "ROSSI",
  "cn": "MARIO ROSSI",
  "groups": [
    "cn=LOYALTY_ADMINISTRATOR,ou=Groups,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT"
  ],
  "upn": "uid=btelefonicacv,ou=People,O=MYCOMPANY,C=IT"
}
```

Any help appreciated

Thanks

Comment: What features are you using (e.g. from your server.xml file)?

Comment: <featureManager>
  <feature>microProfile-3.2</feature>
  <feature>usr:opentracingJaeger-0.33.1</feature>
     <feature>localConnector-1.0</feature>
    </featureManager>

Comment: My guess is you need to add the  `<feature>appSecurity-3.0</feature>` but I'll pass this question along.

Comment: Do you have `<mpJwt >` element correctly configured? Also look into the `message.log` for specific errors as it might provide you with additional information why it is failing. 
You could try also to add binding information to the server.xml instead of ibm-application-bnd file.

Comment: I think my mpJwt is correctly configured.
<mpJwt id="picoMpJwt" issuer="https://localhost:9445/oidc/endpoint/OP" jwksUri="https://localhost:9445/oidc/endpoint/OP/jwk" sharedKey="password" signatureAlgorithm="HS256"/>

In documentation i find that I can configure binding info in server.xml only for WAR. In my case I have EAR file

Comment: Adding feature: appSecurity-3.0 caused that JWT token was no more recognized. So I have NullPointerException on every call to token, for example token.getGroups(), token.getSubject() and so on.